# Unexpected output in a For loop. Batch Windows

Tags: batch-file

im trying to make a little batch to unzip compressed files i have scatered in a really big folder with lots of sub folders and sub sub folders.

```
for /d %a in ("E:\Mis Documentos\Nueva Carpeta\*") do for /d %b in ("%a\*") do if EXIST %b/*.zip for /F "delims=" %c in ("%b\*.zip") do 7za.exe e %c
```

The problem is that when it gets to a folder where the if is true the answer is " the system cannot find the file E:\Mis ". So its still breaking the file path by the spaces even when i put the "delims=" option.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

(ACLARATION: i didnt include the extra % before the parameters because i'm testing it directly on the cmd prompt)

**UPDATE:**
Added the qoutes, now it gets to run de 7za command, but when it runs it the path that appears is
    ( folderpath \ *.zip ) 
instead of the specific instance of the file. As if its not iterating the folder at all.

Comment: Is the double quote mismatch not a problem?

Comment: Add quotes around the paths everywhere they appear, e.g. `in (%b\*.zip)` -> `in ("%b\*.zip")`

Comment: Sorry there were some silly mistakes, for not copy pasting. I just wrote the code from memory :P.

anyway i tried it adding the quotes and it still dont work i will update the new error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rem your code
for /d %a in ("E:\Mis Documentos\Nueva Carpeta\*") do for /d %b in ("%a\*") do if EXIST  %b/*.zip  for /F "delims=" %c in ("%b\*.zip") do 7za.exe e  %c
rem changes                                                                             v  ^     v          ^                                       v  v
for /d %a in ("E:\Mis Documentos\Nueva Carpeta\*") do for /d %b in ("%a\*") do if EXIST "%b\*.zip" for              %c in ("%b\*.zip") do 7za.exe e "%c"
```

Main change: `for /F "delims=" %c in ("%b\*.zip") do ...` treats `"%b\*.zip"` text *literally* (after expanding `%b`, of course).

Use `... do ECHO 7za.exe e "%c"` for debugging purposes...
To get *pure* output without annoying commands echo, add some `@` as follows:

```
for /d %a in ("E:\Mis Documentos\Nueva Carpeta\*") do @for /d %b in ("%a\*") do @if EXIST "%b\*.zip" @for %c in ("%b\*.zip") do @ECHO 7za.exe e "%c"
```

**Edit**: required reading

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`for` special page) [FOR command summary: all variants](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

And *quoting filenames containing a space character* is a must (necessity), see next examples:

If all folders `a` and `b` and `a b` exist (note error message):

```
==>if exist a b\*.txt echo yes
The system cannot find the path specified.

==>if exist "a b\*.txt" echo yes
yes
```

If neither `p` nor `q` nor `p q` folder exist (no error message):

```
==>if exist p q\*.txt echo yes

==>if exist "p q\*.txt" echo yes

==>
```

Comment: Wow, that completely worked! but i dont understand why! would you mind explaining me ?Like, why did you added the quotes after the if exists declaration. And why the for loop stopped cutting the file path even when you took out the "delims=".                                                                     Also (and this probably should be a question for another thread)... is there a way to make the answering for the decompression automatical. Like /y for xcopy but for the 7za command?

THANK YOU! A lot, really.